# How to check which linux system user is logging to the mysql database?

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, logging, users

Is it possible to check witch user logged to the Debian server log in to the MySql or some solution to create that thing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, MySQL has a complete separate user database and there is no connection at all between a unix user and a MySQL user, given you no option to reliaby  determine the unix user used.

However, with both MySQL Enterprise and MariaDB you can use alternative auth methods that you can use to authenticate against an OS user (e.g. LDAP, PAM or unix domain sockets).